# How does pytorch perform the reverse-differentiation given an indexed version of a tensor in the feedforward step?

Tags: pytorch

*Some of this code was adapted from the book Deep learning with Pytorch*

Script: Linear regression (trying to predict t_c given t_u)

```py
t_c = torch.tensor([0.5, 14.0, 15.0, 28.0, 11.0, 8.0,
                    3.0, -4.0, 6.0, 13.0, 21.0])
t_u = torch.tensor([35.7, 55.9, 58.2, 81.9, 56.3, 48.9,
                    33.9, 21.8, 48.4, 60.4, 68.4])

def model(t_u, w, b):
    return w * t_u + b

def loss_fn(t_p, t_c):
    squared_diffs = (t_p - t_c)**2
    return squared_diffs.mean()

params = torch.tensor([1.0, 0.0], requires_grad=True)

loss = loss_fn(model(t_u, params[0], params[1]), t_c)
loss.backward()

print(params.grad)
```

Here I am passing in the 0th and 1st index of `params` as an input to the `model` function, which performs scalar-to-vector multiplication and addition.

My question is, what is PyTorch exactly doing to compute the gradients of the `params` tensor? The "feedforward" step uses two subtensors of the `params` tensor, rather than separate tensors for bias and weight, which is what I am familiar with.

My guess is: `params[0]` and `params[1]` are both references to elements in `params`, and they both have their own distinct gradients stored somewhere in the `params.grad`. So the `.backward()` call is treating `params[0]` and `params[1]` as new individual tensors (as if we temporarily had two separate tensors -`weight` and `bias`) and updates their gradients (`params[0].grad`, `params[1].grad`), hence updating the `params.grad` since they are references to it.

Answer (score 1):

The main idea here is that the indexing operation returns a new view of the tensor. If you are not using in-place operations (+=, -=, etc.), the "view" thing does not really matter and you can consider it as just another tensor.

In that case, the indexing operation is no different from other operations like addition or matrix-multiplication -- input (original tensor), output (selected tensor), and gradient (1 if selected, zero otherwise*). Then back-propagation happens as usual.

* More specifically, the gradient of an input entry with respect to an output entry is 1 if the output entry is selected from the input entry; 0 otherwise.

EDIT:
Maybe it's easier to see it this way:

```
a = d_params[0]
c = W*a+b
--------------------------
dc/d_params 
= dc/{d_params[0], d_params[1], d_params[2], ...}
--------------------------
dc/d_params[0]
= dc/da * da/d_params[0]
= dc/da * 1
= W
--------------------------
dc/d_params[1], dc/d_params[2], ... = 0
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I fully understand. Do you mean that d_params/d_params[0] = 1? For this example, if we had separate weight and bias tensors, we would have dC/dW and dC/dB. Now with the differentiable indexing operation, how would I express the chain rule expression of dC/d_params?